# Qt virtual keyboard for Qt application running on Linux host

Tags: linux, qt

I am working on a Qt application on my host Linux system, and want to know as to how I can get the virtual keyboard plugin installed on my machine.

I am using the Qt 5.5.1 runtime with Qt Creator 3.6.1 on Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have not been able to track down the virtual keyboard plugin, which I understand is available for Qt5, in any Qt5 installation directory on my Linux filesystem.

However, based on my research online, I have come to the understanding that other folks have used the Qt virtual keyboard on Linux but, I still don't know how to get the plugin.

Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Subbu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Run Qt Maintenance tool (you can find it in your Qt directory .../Qt/MaintenanceTool).
- Install virtual keyboard

[image: Virtual Keyboard]

- Test it in example [Qt Quick Virtual Keyboard - Basic Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html)

If I recall correctly one needs to add a plugin in .pro file to enable Virtual Keyboard.

```
static {
    QTPLUGIN += qtvirtualkeyboardplugin
}
```

Comment: Eligijus Pupeikis, thanks for reference, I am also looking for how to interact with QT Virtual keyboard?